# Where should I expound my theories?

Tags: discussion

From what I'm understanding, StackExchange is a **Question-and-Answer-Only** website!

It's **NOT** for any discussions or hypothesize or whatsoever!

But then, where should I go if I got some theories I like to share with everybody else!?

Immature theories might it be, but it may trigger brighter minds to discover new possibilities!

So, if you guys could be so kind and refer me to a website as creditable as StackExchange where I could share my hypothesis and theories.

Comment: Start a blog, contact your local university and ask to talk to someone, try reddit.com, facebook.com, twitter.com and other social media sites, phrase your theories as questions, google to see if others have presented the same theories, ask people to debunk your theory on skeptics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why do you need a website?   Couldn't you mail your theories direct to the university of your choice?   Have you taken any university classes in your subject?  Discussed with professors?

Comment: The correct answer is: Don't.  Until you've established some bona fides in your field of research, anything you publish as "my theories" will quite rightfully be ignored as crackpot science.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a blog, post on twitter or even join a university, spend 7 years studying and learn how science is done.

But what if you want to post here?  I propose three tests

- Can the "theory" be broken down into small chunks that can be asked about?
- Can the question chunks be answered?
- Are you willing to change your mind?

If it fails the first, it is too broad.

If it fails the second it is primarily opinion based.

If it fails the third it is a rant, not a genuine inquiry.

---

For example:

> I think the universe is powered by electricity, what do you think guys?

Is not an acceptable question It is unclear, too broad, and posed as a discussion point.

Also unacceptable is:

> Could gravity be a form of magnetism?

(It is unclear what that question means.)  However, questions that may be posed by Electric Universe theories can be asked:

> What causes the temperature of the sun's atmosphere to increase away from the photosphere and not follow an "inverse square law"?

Is perfectly ok, providing you are happy to accept that there is now a good explanation for this and can accept that this is no proof that the sun in powered by an invisible arc of electric plasma.

Answer (score -16):

Excellent question.

For some reason, Stack Exchange - or at least, those running it - allow only a very small sliver of thought. If anybody comes and says anything that goes against their theories, that person will be immediately voted down, shut down and have his questions/answers deleted.

And, of course, they do not allow discussion.

Evidently, the Physics/Astronomy/Space Exploration/Politics forums exist merely to cater for a very small 'elite' of users. And they are religious-like in their dogma.

Comment: Small sliver of thought?     Dogma?     I don't find your answer useful.    There are ways to phrase theories as questions.   It's just not well received to post them as theories.

Comment: The rules on sites like Physics SE restrict questions to mainstream (broadly accepted) theories and the reason is that these sites are considered knowledge bases to *help* people specifically studying (formally or as a hobby) to understand *mainstream* concept.  In fact most (if not all) of the people answering are keen to teach their subjects (and some actually are teachers).  These sites were never intended as discussion forums or for fringe theories.  As for "small sliver", Physics SE allows questions on any of the vast array of mainstream theories.  Good luck learning all that in one life.

Comment: @StephenG Okay. But what about when the small number of physicists who dictate 'mainstream theories' have begun to lose the ability to accept anything beyond said theories and 'laws'? Example: The theory that all matter - and even space and time! - in the universe was once compacted into a point smaller than an atom. Do you actually realise how insane that sounds? And yet, on here, challenging that is not permitted.

Comment: On SE the general community "dictates" what is mainstream by voting on any suggestion to close a question as being off-mainstream or personal (and voting on reopen motions when that happens).  In fact if you can gain support via a meta question you could contribute to a rule change.  This is how democracy works on SE.

Comment: @WhitePrime "How insane that sounds".  Yes, anyone who's studied the history of physics knows exactly how insane that sounds.  "big bang" - ridiculous.   "Black holes" - "that shows the limits of Einstein's theories, we know those can't be real"  We're too smart to believe in that.  These ideas were preposterous to mainstream physics for years, but the evidence supports them.  Today we go with the evidence, it leads to better results than opinion, which used to play a bigger role.

Comment: @WhitePrime and the day science is based on democracy will be a very bad day for science.