# I can't find this question. Was it deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-questions

Yesterday I remember I answered a question about the formation of the planets in the solar system by the user [Kerry Frost](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/46675/kerry-frost). There was some debate in the comments on whether the question should have been closed. After a few hours I couldn't find the question anymore.

Today I saw in [another post](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49897/42349) that the OP is asking for their previous question to be undeleted.

Has the question on planet formation really been deleted? And if so, why?

I am not arguing against the closing of the question. This is something that is decided through votes by the community or by the moderators. I am asking about the reasons of the deletion, because this is not something that I have seen happening often to questions that are not spam/rude/abusive.

In their [new question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/49891/42349) the OP has shown an attitude that I don't like, and has proven to be reticent or completely unable to accept answers that don't agree with their point of view. This was not evident in their previous question, but would this be a valid reason for deleting it in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/49883/have-the-planets-actually-originated-from-the-sun-as-globules-of-molten-matter .  You should be able to see every question Kerry Frost has posted by going through their profile.

I noticed a "spam" flag on this post due to the promotion of the OP's website.  I didn't close this post, but I think the closure was justified.

We get a number of posts on this site concerning theories far outside of mainstream astronomy. Many times they are disingenuous, using the site to promote their theories rather than truly asking a question to learn something. While I think we should usually give posters the benefit of the doubt, I think the referenced post clearly falls into this category.

There are already plenty of outstanding posts on this site concerning planet formation, such as [Why do planets and satellites in the Solar system look so wildly different if they came from more or less the same matter?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29978/why-do-planets-and-satellites-in-the-solar-system-look-so-wildly-different-if-th) .

Comment: That's weird, I looked at this user's profile, but I couldn't see the deleted question. Maybe I don't have enough reputation. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Prallax yes I think you need 10K rep to be able to see deleted posts

Answer (score 5):

I was the one who cast the final close vote and deleted the question. I let the OP know in a comment that this sort of "prove my personal theory wrong" type question, used to draw attention to the user's website, is not allowed here. I pointed them to this meta guidance: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/436/6.

Comment: Nice resource, useful reference for the future, thank you